# VB .net class library

Tags: winforms

I get a doubt about Class Library application type, so I need help on this.

I get a software I can add plugin to. I want to make this plugin in VB.NET using Visual Studio 2010.
The software only accept class library application type only and I need to display a Form with a Combobox in order for the user to pickup a value in a list.

In the main class that is first launched when the software calls the plugin. I launch a Windows Form in the code below the object's name is objListValidation. My problem is that when I do the Me.Show() it displays the window, but it's going to the end of the CompareToList function and doesn't stop there.

Code that launch the Win Form:

```
Public objListValidation As ListValidation

objListValidation = New ListValidation
objListValidation.CompareToList("SELECT <NOM_CHAMP> FROM <NOM_TABLE>")
```

Code that display the Win Form:

```
Public Sub CompareToList(ByVal qryStr As String, Optional ByVal isBloquant As Boolean = False)
    Dim alCompteGeneraux As New ArrayList
    Dim isExistsInList As Boolean = False

    Dim objConnectDB2 As New ConnectDB2
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    If Not isBloquant Then btnCancel.Visible = True : manageButtonsPosition() Else mstrIsBloquant = True
    al.Add("AAA")
    al.Add("VVVV")
    al.Add("BBBB")

    For i = 0 To al.Count - 1
        If al.Item(i).ToString = mstrObjInvoiceField.DisplayString Then isExistsInList = True
    Next

    If Not isExistsInList Then
        Me.Text = "Liste de choix pour le champ : " + mstrObjInvoiceField.Name
        lblTitle.Text = "Veuillez choisir dans la liste une valeur pour le champ : " + mstrObjInvoiceField.Name
        cbList.DataSource = al
        Me.Show()
    Else
        validation()
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to call `Me.ShowDialog()`, which won't return until the user closes the dialog.